# Linux running part of script at start up

Tags: linux, shell, startup

and thank you for being so helpful. I am trying to run a script at startup that reduces the power limits of my gpus. The shell command is in init.d and I have tried using symlink to rc1 and rc3. The shell command has also been made executable using Chmod +x. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 as well. When I restart the computer only 1 card drops the wattage to the appropriate level while the other two stay unchanged. This is gpu0. Any help would be much appreciated. I have also tried using Crontab and have had difficulties. My script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Run as sudo to lower power-limits."
echo ""

nvidia-smi -i 0 -pl 100
nvidia-smi -i 1 -pl 100
nvidia-smi -i 2 -pl 100

echo ""
echo ""

nvidia-smi
```

Comment: Does the script work if you run it by hand?

Comment: Yes. In terminal if I run sudo ./reduce-power-limit.sh all the cards change to the correct wattage

Comment: I think unix.stackexchange.com would probably be able to answer this better. And why did you undo my formatting changes?

Comment: I didn’t mean too. When I pasted the script it didn’t go in correctly. We must have been editing at the same time.

Comment: If not in your `.bash_profile` (or `.profile`), depending on your Desktop (gnome, kde, xfce, etc..), each generally has a location for per-user startup scripts (you can just put a link there) E.g., for kde it is `~/.kde/Autostart` (it may even be something specified in the xdg setup). Otherwise, for system wide setup, most distros (I don't know about Ubuntu specifically) provide a `boot.local` or `after.local` script that will execute your custom command at various points in the boot process. Look into that as well.

Comment: I am not sure of the location of these. I have done a lot of research on running at startup. It’s just weird 1 card does it and the rest don’t.

Comment: Try running the following in a terminal to find the full path `which nvidia-smi`. Then add a new line at line 2 of your script that sets your PATH to include the result, e.g. `PATH=$PATH:/path/to/nvidia/stuff`

Comment: So add it as PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/nvidia-smi   To Line 2?

Comment: No, you add the names of **directories** which *contain* binaries. So if your binary is `/usr/bin/program` you need to add `/usr/bin` to your PATH, i.e. `PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin`